# Creating Different log files using log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to write logs in different files. I want to be able to write into different files from different methods. Say if there is an exception in Method A it writes in File A...if there is an exception in Method B write in File B. I read help on google, but they all suggest the debug, trace etc etc levels. My messages are all error messages, just the methods are different. I am using properties file for log4j. This is what it looks like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, ROOT
log4j.appender.ROOT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROOT.File=(**my_path**)\EmailIntegration.log
log4j.appender.ROOT.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.ROOT.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.ROOT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.ROOT.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %t %c %-5p - %m%n
log4j.logger.com.webage.ejbs=INFO
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Define your `log4j.rootLogger`.
2. Configure your rootLogger to an appender.
3. Define what root logger must the class log to.

Example (my root logger is `stdout`, `infoout`, `debugout`, `errorout`).

```
#---This is the configuration file for Log4J---
log4j.threshold=ALL
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout, infoout, debugout, errorout
```

Then I defined each logger (e.g. `infoout`)

```
#--Log settings for infoout
log4j.appender.infoout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infoout.file=C:/Logs/Music4Point0.info.log
log4j.appender.infoout.MaxFileSize=10240KB
log4j.appender.infoout.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.infoout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infoout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MMM-yyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.infoout.Threshold=INFO
```

Now, I said that all `org.hibernate.*` classes must log to `DEBUG` threshold and `infoout` logger.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG, infoout
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate=false
```

That's how you configure log4J to setup your custom logging.

Answer (score 1):

The finest level of control in log4j is at class level. Anyway, you have two options:

First option, the simplest one, is to define special loggers for each method:

```
log4j.logger.LoggerForMethodA=ERRROR, APPENDERFORMETHODA
log4j.logger.LoggerForMethodB=ERRROR, APPENDERFORMETHODB
```

And in your class, use the appropiate logger on your methods.

The second option, the powerful one, is to switch to the xml configuration format, where you can define filters for each appender I think this is your best option. Check out [the explanation](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) on the XML configuration format, and [how to use filters in log4j](http://codedependents.com/2008/11/21/controlling-log4j-logs-with-contexts-and-filters/). That way you define one appender per file, and use the filter to guarantee that the exception goes to the proper file.
Also take a look at the javadocs for the [Filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html), [Logging Event](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html) and [LocationInfo](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LocationInfo.html)